# Can't iterate through multiple selector ($$, findElements) webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver, electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I'm trying to use webdriver.io (https://webdriver.io/) with spectron for an electron application.

I'm able to access functions that findElement or $ contain. For example, I can use the .click() on this findElement ($) selector.

`app.client.$('//button[@data-value, "Agree")]').click()`

My application contains 4 buttons that have a data-value prop of Agree. This $ selector will just click on the first one. My goal is to iterate through alll of the "Agree" buttons and click on all of them.

I'm trying to do this:

`app.client.$$('//button[@data-value, "Agree")]').forEach(button => button.click())`

However, that's saying the forEach function doesn't exist as if app.client.$$ doesn't return an array, contrary to what this documentation says: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$.html

If I try to resolve the promise returned by $$, by doing:

`app.client.$$('//button[@data-value, "Agree")]').then(buttons => console.log(buttons))`

I get an array of the 4 buttons, but only the ELEMENT identifier, index and element object id appear. They do not include an extended prototype to run commands like .click() on them. I also cannot find any way to query for a particular ELEMENT ID using webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade from v4 to v5 or ideally to v6.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm using https://www.electronjs.org/spectron which is built on top of webdriverIO. I'm using v10.0.0 of spectron. Are there any other options besides upgrading webdriverIO?

Comment: WebdriverIO v5 and v6 both support nodejs 10.

Comment: You have to convert every json wire element (buttons) to WebdriverIO object in v4. Don't have a code snippet atm. Do you need help with that?

Comment: Yeah that would be great!